# Simple deployment to Ec2

Tags: linux, php, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have a fairly simple PHP application (CakePhp) that has been moved to the clients EC2 account.  I'd now like to set up a simple deployment process for it. These are the steps I want:

1. Deploy changes to files in the git account.
2. Run composer.

I'm only allowed to use Bitbucket, where the repo is now stored, and AWS services.  I have SSH access, but it is via a Jump/Bastion server.

What is the simplest/most sane way to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Brief answer: from **Bitbucket** trigger **AWS CodePipeline** and from CodePipeline run **AWS CodeDeploy** to push the code updates to the EC2 instance.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks.  Doesn't code deploy inisist on deploying the whole server architecture though? So re-installing apache, php+modules etc.

Comment: @Will nope, CodeDeploy runs an agent on the instance and it then runs a deployment script that you provide. What you do in the script is up to you. Typically it just replaces the PHP source code with a new version and perhaps restarts Apache.